# NgModel not updating model in checkbox

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox

I have a model that basically is a list of objects, and each of this objects contains a boolean value. These boolean values must be updatable by the user so I wrote a component that creates a checkbox for each object and then I bind this checkbox with the model behind it.

This however is not working! If I check a checkbox, the model it is bound to seems to not be updated at all.

To illustrate my problem, I created a minimal working example:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-test',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="!!data">
            <div *ngFor="let item of data">
                <ion-checkbox ([ngModel])="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-button (click)="console_log()">print output</ion-button>
    `
})
export class TestComponent {
    @Input() data: any;

    console_log() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'page-test',
    template: `
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                <ion-title>
                    Test
                </ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <component-test [data]="params.data | async"></component-test>
        </ion-content>
    `
})
export class TestPage implements OnInit {

    params: any = {};

    async get_data() {
        return [{checked: false}, {checked: false}, {checked: false}];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.params['data'] = this.get_data();
    }
}
```

As you can see:

- the data is asynchronously loaded in a parent component (page-test)
- the data is passed to a testcomponent (which contains the checkboxes) (component-test)
- I added a button that outputs the data in the console to verify the current state of the model.

The expected behaviour:

- when I toggle a checkbox, the boolean in the model should mirror the state of the checkbox and vice versa

The observed behaviour:

- When I toggle a checkbox and output the model to the console, I observe no change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModel` syntax is wrong because of this the checkbox value is not binded, so please change it like this

```
<div *ngIf="!!data">
            <div *ngFor="let item of data">
                <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake in my minimal working example, but it does not solve the problem I have in my real component. At least I can now start pinpointing what the real problem is!

Answer (score 2):

You code is correct but you have made a little mistake... the ngModel should be written as  **[(ngModel)]** not **([ngModel])**   famous line : banana in the box not box in the banana.  :)

so the code will be :

```
<div *ngIf="!!data">
            <div *ngFor="let item of data">
                <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written `ngModel` incorrectly. Proper way of two way binding syntax is

`[(attribute or prop)]`

code:

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in the end (all other answers are valid as well) is to make sure that the FormsModule is imported in your module.

If the component is lazy loaded, it didn't give an error message but the "lazy module" still requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap + Angular example:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="checkbox"
      (change)="form.checkbox = !form.checkbox";
        changed[exchangeId] = true"
      [checked]="form.checkbox"
    />
    <span class="form-check-sign"> </span> Agree
  </label>
</div>
```